# Need help individually controlling 3 LEDs with 3 toggle switches

Tags: arduino-nano

I'm trying to individually control 3 LEDs with 3 toggle switches. This is the code I'm using

```cpp
#define LED_PIN1 2  
#define BUTTON_PIN1 14

#define LED_PIN2 3
#define BUTTON_PIN2 15

#define LED_PIN3 4
#define BUTTON_PIN3 16

void setup() {
  pinMode(LED_PIN1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(BUTTON_PIN1, INPUT);

   pinMode(LED_PIN2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(BUTTON_PIN2, INPUT);

   pinMode(LED_PIN3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(BUTTON_PIN3, INPUT);

}
void loop() {
  if (digitalRead(BUTTON_PIN1) == HIGH) {
    digitalWrite(LED_PIN1, HIGH);
  }
  if (digitalRead(BUTTON_PIN1) == LOW)   {
    digitalWrite(LED_PIN1, LOW);
  }
  if (digitalRead(BUTTON_PIN2) == HIGH) {
    digitalWrite(LED_PIN2, HIGH);
  }
  if (digitalRead(BUTTON_PIN2) == LOW) {
    digitalWrite(LED_PIN2, LOW);
  }
  if (digitalRead(BUTTON_PIN3) == HIGH) {
    digitalWrite(LED_PIN3, HIGH);
  }
  if (digitalRead(BUTTON_PIN3) == LOW) {
    digitalWrite(LED_PIN3, LOW);
  }
}
```

The problem is that this code is causing all 3 LEDs to turn on or off together when any one of the three toggle switches is pushed. Can someone explain why this is happening? Also, what do I need to change so that each LED can be individually controlled?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using an external pullup or pulldown resistor for each button?

Answer (score 3):

How is your wiring done?

This is a working example of how it can be done:

```cpp
#define LED_PIN1 5  
#define BUTTON_PIN1 14

#define LED_PIN2 6
#define BUTTON_PIN2 15

#define LED_PIN3 7
#define BUTTON_PIN3 16

void setup() {
  // set up all the LEDs as OUTPUT
  pinMode(LED_PIN1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LED_PIN2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LED_PIN3, OUTPUT);
  
  // set up all the buttons as INPUT
  pinMode(BUTTON_PIN1, INPUT);
  pinMode(BUTTON_PIN2, INPUT);
  pinMode(BUTTON_PIN3, INPUT);
}

void loop() {
  // turn the LED on when button is pressed
  digitalWrite(LED_PIN1, digitalRead(BUTTON_PIN1));
  digitalWrite(LED_PIN2, digitalRead(BUTTON_PIN2));
  digitalWrite(LED_PIN3, digitalRead(BUTTON_PIN3)); 
}
```

When you just want the LED to be on when the button is pressed and off when the button is unpressed you can simplify the code by directly writing the button state to the LED like so: `digitalWrite(LED_PIN, digitalRead(BUTTON_PIN))`. Because read of the button will return either `HIGH` or `LOW` you can directly drive the LED with this.

Also make sure you check the pin's you are using on your device. Pin 3 is the reset pin. I therefore changed the pins to 5, 6, 7 to make sure you're using digital pins.
[image: Arduino Nano pinlayout]

If you want to see a working example in action, take a look at [this](https://www.tinkercad.com/things/6GXuqA5nYlP?sharecode=iEpjt-7qtN6PoFT5d26U1lMg5scu4wfO36ZPCcjMCwc) tinkercad. Be aware that I'm using an arduino uno here, so make sure that you use correct pins using the previous pin layout when adapting this to your Arduino nano. You can simulate this circuit by clicking on the 'simulate' button and test this working example by clicking on the buttons in the circuit.
[image]